# Problem in execution of error call in ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
        url: solrURL+"/solr/db/select/?qt=dismax&wt=json&&start="+start+"&rows="+end+"&q="+query+"&json.wrf=?",
        async:false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(){
                    getSolrResponse(sort,order,itemPerPage,showPage,query,solrURL);  
                        }
        ,error:function(){

                alert("there is an error");
                }

})
```

I have this ajax request, but even if url is not correct, than also error code is not executing, why so. please tell me the solution.

Comment: Please fix the indenting of your code.

Comment: kingjiv: Thanks kingjiv, I hope it is readable now

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the async: false setting and tell us if it helped.

Use FireBug Net panel to debug the AJAX request - just see the request and response. THen you can open the request in new tab and play with it

Comment: Tomas Telensky: its stil not working :(:(...please tell me the solution, its really very urgent

Comment: Use FireBug Net panel to debug the AJAX request - just see the request and response. THen you can open the request in new tab and play with it.